# Azure WebBot-Cortana OAUTH Issue "POST to 'https://CortanaBFChannelWestUS.azurewebsites.net

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azureportal, cortana-skills-kit, cortana-invoke

**Problem:**

Error: POST to 'https://CortanaBFChannelWestUS.azurewebsites.net/v3/conversations/../activities/6TZfwIQ7Fqv' failed: [500] Internal Server Error
    at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:675:46)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

**Architecture:**
Aure Web-Bot : NodeJS SDKv3 
Microsoft App Dev 
Luis
Channels : Web/Cortana/Skype
OAuth

**Scenario:** 
Upon hitting an intent based on an utterance the app successfully displays a "sign-in" card to the user and asks the user to sign in

[Screenshot of app sign-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzEGl.png)

After that the user is able to successfully log in using credentials that are authenticated using OAuth for access to Office 365

[ScreenShot after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLhco.png)

**TestCase:** 
Channel Skype: Successful display and login 
Channel Web: Successful display and login 
Channel Cortana: Fail ( No display of "sign-in"card)

Channel Cortana: Fail ( No display of "sign-in"card)
Now i am using the Cortana app on an iphone and for the same utterance-intent-action this is what happens

[Screen Shot Channel Cortana Invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI7ej.jpg)

And the error that shows up on the console is as shown above

**Notes:**

Within the Web-Bot framework When it is Skype or Web as a channel the callback for the OAuth is mapped to

```
server.get('/api/OAuthCallback',
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/'}),
    (req, res) => {
    const address = JSON.parse(req.query.state);
    const messageData = { accessToken: req.user.accessToken, refreshToken: req.user.refreshToken, userId: address.user.id, name: req.user.displayName};
    var continueMsg = new builder.Message().address(address).text(JSON.stringify(messageData));
    bot.receive(continueMsg.toMessage());
    res.send('Welcome ' + req.user.displayName + '. Login successful. You can close this browser window')
});
```

The basic idea for the OAuth as implemented being that the URl maps to a call back as defined in the Web-App-Platform.

But Cortana does say [Cortana MSA Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account) and that didnt work

1. For one there URL maps to https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth instead of the call back defined at the web-app-bot-url/api/OAuthCallback
2. Can someone explain how does the Authentication work for Cortana given the arch they have specified

Can anyone shed some light as to what exactly is the problem i know i am missing something important as far as understanding is concerned.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for this.

Cortana's OAuth works differently from botframework.

Starting with the app registration; IF you turn on Cortana's "manage identity for you", Cortana will send the login card IF you turn on "sign in at invocation".  Your bot never needs to send the login card as an attachment if Cortana is the channel. You register Microsoft AAD oauth endpoints on the Cortana channel config page, and then your app registration has the redirect url to https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth to let Cortana know what the auth token is.

Next, using Cortana's auth token, you will get it on the activity (message) after log in. With botframework, it is kept in keystore so you need to go get it.

If you do not have "sign in at invocation" on, you send an oauth card as an attachment and then Cortana will start the oauth flow, but only title is used in render of the login request by Cortana.

Note that the app registration; the redirect url has to be from the same domain as the initiator of the oauth flow.  (And for Cortana, that is bing.)

If you do not want to use Cortana's OAuth, you leave the "Cortana will manage my identity" off. Use a sign in card and manage the oauth yourself. But then, don't forget you need to manage refresh tokens too (that Cortana will do for you if you use offline_access scope).

You can find more about Cortana oauth here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/authentication

I have some draft documentation on differences here;
https://github.com/bw-kforce-ms/CortanaSkillsWIP/blob/master/Support/OAuth.md

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Bud , Thanks so much for that information. I guess i do need to figure out that if that channel is Cortana then i shoudlnt send in the card versus the "sign in at invocation" which auto generates that. 

I will give this a shot as you have detailed out and see how i make progress. Again thank you so much for reaching out

Comment: No problem, there is node and C# examples for Cortana only oauth here https://github.com/Microsoft/cortana-skills-samples

Comment: Thanks :) i ll take a look at that code base now! you rock

Answer (score 0):

@Micromuncher , Bud , i finally got some basic the code work. What i missed out on was the simplicity of the way the the token is obtained. Having used passport previously for obtaining the Auth Code and the complexity involved in it, I think ended up over-engineering the thought process earlier.

Now to find out how to make this channel specific such that only for Cortana use the Cortana-flow and everything else use the passport-openid flow.

Thanks !